# org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: For input string: "30s" in ignite hadoop execution

Tags: hadoop, ignite

I want to execute a wordcount example of `Hadoop` over `apache ignite`. I have used IGFS as cache for HDFS configuration in ignite, but after submitting job via Hadoop for execution on ignite I encountered with below error.

Thanks in advance to anyone who could help me!

```html
Using configuration: examples/config/filesystem/example-igfs-hdfs.xml

[00:47:13]    __________  ________________ 
[00:47:13]   /  _/ ___/ |/ /  _/_  __/ __/ 
[00:47:13]  _/ // (7 7    // /  / / / _/   
[00:47:13] /___/\___/_/|_/___/ /_/ /___/  
[00:47:13] 
[00:47:13] ver. 2.6.0#20180710-sha1:669feacc
[00:47:13] 2018 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
[00:47:13] 
[00:47:13] Ignite documentation: http://ignite.apache.org
[00:47:13] 
[00:47:13] Quiet mode.
[00:47:13]   ^-- Logging to file '/usr/local/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/work/log/ignite-f3712946.log'
[00:47:13]   ^-- Logging by 'Log4JLogger [quiet=true, config=/usr/local/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/config/ignite-log4j.xml]'
[00:47:13]   ^-- To see **FULL** console log here add -DIGNITE_QUIET=false or "-v" to ignite.{sh|bat}
[00:47:13] 
[00:47:13] OS: Linux 4.15.0-46-generic amd64
[00:47:13] VM information: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_192-ea-b04 Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.192-b04
[00:47:13] Configured plugins:
[00:47:13]   ^-- Ignite Native I/O Plugin [Direct I/O] 
[00:47:13]   ^-- Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
[00:47:13] 
[00:47:13] Configured failure handler: [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0]]
[00:47:22] Message queue limit is set to 0 which may lead to potential OOMEs when running cache operations in FULL_ASYNC or PRIMARY_SYNC modes due to message queues growth on sender and receiver sides.
[00:47:22] Security status [authentication=off, tls/ssl=off]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/slf4j-nop-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/htrace%20dependency/slf4j-nop-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/ignite-rest-http/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/ignite-yarn/ignite-yarn-2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/ignite-zookeeper/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory]
[00:47:23] HADOOP_HOME is set to /usr/local/hadoop
[00:47:23] Resolved Hadoop classpath locations: /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common, /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs, /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce
[00:47:26] Performance suggestions for grid  (fix if possible)
[00:47:26] To disable, set -DIGNITE_PERFORMANCE_SUGGESTIONS_DISABLED=true
[00:47:26]   ^-- Enable G1 Garbage Collector (add '-XX:+UseG1GC' to JVM options)
[00:47:26]   ^-- Set max direct memory size if getting 'OOME: Direct buffer memory' (add '-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=<size>[g|G|m|M|k|K]' to JVM options)
[00:47:26]   ^-- Disable processing of calls to System.gc() (add '-XX:+DisableExplicitGC' to JVM options)
[00:47:26]   ^-- Enable ATOMIC mode if not using transactions (set 'atomicityMode' to ATOMIC)
[00:47:26]   ^-- Disable fully synchronous writes (set 'writeSynchronizationMode' to PRIMARY_SYNC or FULL_ASYNC)
[00:47:26] Refer to this page for more performance suggestions: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jvm-and-system-tuning
[00:47:26] 
[00:47:26] To start Console Management & Monitoring run ignitevisorcmd.{sh|bat}
[00:47:26] 
[00:47:26] Ignite node started OK (id=f3712946)
[00:47:26] Topology snapshot [ver=1, servers=1, clients=0, CPUs=8, offheap=1.6GB, heap=1.0GB]
[00:47:26]   ^-- Node [id=F3712946-0810-440F-A440-140FE4AB6FA7, clusterState=ACTIVE]
[00:47:26] Data Regions Configured:
[00:47:27]   ^-- default [initSize=256.0 MiB, maxSize=1.6 GiB, persistenceEnabled=false]
[00:47:35] New version is available at ignite.apache.org: 2.7.0
[2019-03-13 00:47:46,978][ERROR][igfs-igfs-ipc-#53][IgfsImpl] File info operation in DUAL mode failed [path=/output]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: For input string: "30s"
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.impl.fs.HadoopLazyConcurrentMap.getOrCreate(HadoopLazyConcurrentMap.java:100)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.impl.delegate.HadoopCachingFileSystemFactoryDelegate.getWithMappedName(HadoopCachingFileSystemFactoryDelegate.java:53)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.impl.delegate.HadoopBasicFileSystemFactoryDelegate.get(HadoopBasicFileSystemFactoryDelegate.java:75)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.impl.delegate.HadoopBasicFileSystemFactoryDelegate.get(HadoopBasicFileSystemFactoryDelegate.java:43)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.impl.delegate.HadoopIgfsSecondaryFileSystemDelegateImpl.fileSystemForUser(HadoopIgfsSecondaryFileSystemDelegateImpl.java:517)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.impl.delegate.HadoopIgfsSecondaryFileSystemDelegateImpl.info(HadoopIgfsSecondaryFileSystemDelegateImpl.java:296)
 at org.apache.ignite.hadoop.fs.IgniteHadoopIgfsSecondaryFileSystem.info(IgniteHadoopIgfsSecondaryFileSystem.java:240)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.igfs.IgfsImpl.resolveFileInfo(IgfsImpl.java:1600)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.igfs.IgfsImpl.access$800(IgfsImpl.java:110)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.igfs.IgfsImpl$6.call(IgfsImpl.java:524)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.igfs.IgfsImpl$6.call(IgfsImpl.java:517)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.igfs.IgfsImpl.safeOp(IgfsImpl.java:1756)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.igfs.IgfsImpl.info(IgfsImpl.java:517)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.igfs.IgfsIpcHandler$2.apply(IgfsIpcHandler.java:341)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.igfs.IgfsIpcHandler$2.apply(IgfsIpcHandler.java:332)
 at org.apache.ignite.igfs.IgfsUserContext.doAs(IgfsUserContext.java:54)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.igfs.IgfsIpcHandler.processPathControlRequest(IgfsIpcHandler.java:332)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.igfs.IgfsIpcHandler.execute(IgfsIpcHandler.java:241)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.igfs.IgfsIpcHandler.access$000(IgfsIpcHandler.java:57)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.igfs.IgfsIpcHandler$1.run(IgfsIpcHandler.java:167)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: For input string: "30s"
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.cast(IgniteUtils.java:7307)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.resolve(GridFutureAdapter.java:259)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get0(GridFutureAdapter.java:171)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get(GridFutureAdapter.java:140)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.impl.fs.HadoopLazyConcurrentMap$ValueWrapper.getValue(HadoopLazyConcurrentMap.java:191)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.impl.fs.HadoopLazyConcurrentMap.getOrCreate(HadoopLazyConcurrentMap.java:93)
 ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "30s"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
 at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
 at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getLong(Configuration.java:1538)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$Conf.<init>(DFSClient.java:430)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:540)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:524)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:146)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3303)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:476)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$1.run(FileSystem.java:217)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$1.run(FileSystem.java:214)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
 at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:214)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.impl.delegate.HadoopBasicFileSystemFactoryDelegate.create(HadoopBasicFileSystemFactoryDelegate.java:117)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.impl.delegate.HadoopBasicFileSystemFactoryDelegate.getWithMappedName(HadoopBasicFileSystemFactoryDelegate.java:95)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.impl.delegate.HadoopCachingFileSystemFactoryDelegate.access$001(HadoopCachingFileSystemFactoryDelegate.java:32)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.impl.delegate.HadoopCachingFileSystemFactoryDelegate$1.createValue(HadoopCachingFileSystemFactoryDelegate.java:37)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.impl.delegate.HadoopCachingFileSystemFactoryDelegate$1.createValue(HadoopCachingFileSystemFactoryDelegate.java:35)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.impl.fs.HadoopLazyConcurrentMap$ValueWrapper.init(HadoopLazyConcurrentMap.java:173)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.impl.fs.HadoopLazyConcurrentMap$ValueWrapper.access$100(HadoopLazyConcurrentMap.java:154)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.impl.fs.HadoopLazyConcurrentMap.getOrCreate(HadoopLazyConcurrentMap.java:82)
 ... 22 more
```

for execution hadoop wordcount example i have created forlder in hdfs as name /user/input/ and put a text file on it and execute wordcout example with below command:
time hadoop --config /home/mehdi/ignite-conf/ignite-configs-master/igfs-hadoop-fs-cache/ignite_conf jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.2.0.jar wordcount /user/input/ /output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check, if you have `dfs.client.datanode-restart.timeout` property specified anywhere in your configuration. It's set to `30s`, but parser expects a number as a value. If you don't have it specified anywhere, then try setting it to `30` explicitly.

The issue comes from the fact, that Ignite uses Hadoop 2.4.1 internally. Configuration parser doesn't support time units on that version. You tried running examples compiled for Hadoop 3.2.0. I would recommend switching to Hadoop 2.4.1 to avoid other compatibility issues.

Comment: But in which file I need to add this if want to add it explicitly ? I am using a simple map reduce job

Comment: @CodeRunner wherever you define your IGFS parameters. Please note that if you experience the same problem, then it's likely that you use a wrong version of Hadoop. Also please note that IGFS is a feature that is no longer supported by the Ignite community. Consider changing your architecture so that it doesn't involve usage of IGFS. You can find more on the following page: https://ignite.apache.org/use-cases/hadoop-acceleration.html#:~:text=Apache%20Ignite%C2%AE%20enables%20real,for%20long%2Drunning%20OLAP%20workloads.

Answer (score 0):

it works! thanks very much. i replaced Hadoop 3.2.0 library in $IGNITE_HOME/lib path with Hadoop 2.4.1 and run example again. it run without any error or exception.! greats.