# Apache Tez Job fails due to java.lang.NumberFormatException for input string: "30s"

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-tez

I am trying to execute query on Apache hive on tez but somehow i am getting the error as below and I have no clue how to solve it

1. Apache Hadoop 3.1.1
2. Apache Hive  3.1.0
3. Apache Tez   0.9.1

My tez-site.xml

```
    <configuration>
        <property>
            <name>tez.lib.uris</name>
            <value>hdfs://localhost:8020/apps/apache-tez-0.9.1-bin/share/tez.tar.gz</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>tez.staging-dir</name>
            <value>/tmp/${user.name}/staging</value>
        </property>
    <configuration>
```

```
020-04-22 21:08:55,530 [INFO] [main] |shim.HadoopShimsLoader|: Trying to locate HadoopShimProvider for hadoopVersion=2.7.0, majorVersion=2, minorVersion=7
2020-04-22 21:08:55,531 [INFO] [main] |shim.HadoopShimsLoader|: Picked HadoopShim org.apache.tez.hadoop.shim.HadoopShim27, providerName=org.apache.tez.hadoop.shim.HadoopShim25_26_27Provider, overrideProviderViaConfig=null, hadoopVersion=2.7.0, majorVersion=2, minorVersion=7
2020-04-22 21:08:55,551 [INFO] [main] |app.DAGAppMaster|: AM Level configured TaskSchedulers: [0:TezYarn:null],[1:TezUber:null]
2020-04-22 21:08:55,551 [INFO] [main] |app.DAGAppMaster|: AM Level configured ContainerLaunchers: [0:TezYarn:null],[1:TezUber:null]
2020-04-22 21:08:55,551 [INFO] [main] |app.DAGAppMaster|: AM Level configured TaskCommunicators: [0:TezYarn:null],[1:TezUber:null]
2020-04-22 21:08:55,551 [INFO] [main] |app.DAGAppMaster|: Comparing client version with AM version, clientVersion=0.9.1, AMVersion=0.9.1
2020-04-22 21:08:55,633 [INFO] [main] |service.AbstractService|: Service org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster failed in state INITED; cause: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "30s"
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "30s"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getLong(Configuration.java:1311)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$Conf.<init>(DFSClient.java:502)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:637)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2653)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2687)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.tez.common.TezCommonUtils.getTezBaseStagingPath(TezCommonUtils.java:87)
    at org.apache.tez.common.TezCommonUtils.getTezSystemStagingPath(TezCommonUtils.java:146)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster.serviceInit(DAGAppMaster.java:492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster$9.run(DAGAppMaster.java:2662)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(DAGAppMaster.java:2659)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster.main(DAGAppMaster.java:2464)
2020-04-22 21:08:55,636 [WARN] [main] |service.AbstractService|: When stopping the service org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster : java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 4):

try to add this property in hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.client.datanode-restart.timeout</name>
    <value>30</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 1):

The default value of the property `dfs.client.datanode-restart.timeout` is *30s*. [This issue is related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55135374/org-apache-ignite-igniteexception-for-input-string-30s-in-ignite-hadoop-exec).

[Here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-12920) is mentioned a workaround. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you reply.. i have already checked my hdfs-site.xml there is no setting that indicate that have value specified as "30s".

```
<property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:///hadoopdata/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///hadoopdata/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.blocksize</name>
    <value>268435456</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.blocksize</name>
    <value>268435456</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.handler.count</name>
    <value>100</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.permissions.superusergroup</name>
    <value>hadoop</value>
    <description>The name of the group of super-users.</description>
</property>
```

Comment: In my case, there's no setting for "30s" but as @alen suggested, add property 
 then it works. (Same version of Hadoop - 3.1.1)

Comment: The issue is with the default value, which is apparently `30s`.